# Jacobi symbol of quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory

In my textbook there's the following definition:

> Let $n$ be an odd number and $n = \prod_{i=1}^s q_i^{r_i}$ its prime factorization. Then the Jacobi symbol is defined as
>   \begin{equation*}
>   \left( \frac{a}{n} \right) = \prod_{i=1}^s\left( \frac{a}{q_i} \right)^{r_i} \, .
> \end{equation*}
>    If $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$, then the Jacobi symbol is $1$. Yet the reverse doesn't necessarily hold.

The symbol on the right side of the equation is the Legendre symbol (confusingly the symbol is "recycled" for the Jacobi symbol).

There is *no* explanation given whatsoever why this:

> If $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$, then the Jacobi symbol is $1$.

is true. Is it trivial and I don't see it? Ok, it seems to follow from the fact that the projection $\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^s (\mathbb{Z}/q_i\mathbb{Z})^{r_i}$ is a ring homomorphism, right?

Ok, and now a counterexample for the assertion:

> Yet the reverse doesn't necessarily hold.

Quadratic residues modulo $15$ are 
      $$ 0, 1, 4, 6, 9, 10 $$
      but $$
        \left( \frac{2}{15} \right) = \left( \frac{2}{5} \right) \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) = (-1)\cdot(-1) = 1\,.$$ Am I right here?

Comment: Isn’t the local factor defined to be zero when $q_i|a$?

Comment: @Lubin: you're right. Too bad. So $\left(\frac{9}{15}\right) = 0$, but of course $x^2 \equiv 9 \bmod{15}$ has a solution. So they should have included "if $\gcd(a, n) = 1$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, $a$ is a QR $\bmod n$ iff $a$ is a QR $\bmod p^k$ for all prime powers $p^k$ dividing $n$. In particular, if $a$ is a QR $\bmod n$, then $a$ is a QR $\bmod p$ for all primes $p$ dividing $n$. Is it clear now?

And your counterexample is fine. The point is that if $n$ is a product of distinct primes then the Jacobi symbol only tells you the parity of the number of prime factors $p$ of $n$ such that $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't it "overkill" to use the CRT? Isn't it enough to know that $\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/q_i \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism? So if $x^2 = a$ is solvable in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ the equation $y^2 = \phi(a)$ must solvable in $\mathbb{Z}/q_i\mathbb{Z}$ because $\phi(x^2) = \phi(a) \Rightarrow \phi(x)^2 = \phi(a)$, which means $y^2 \equiv a \bmod{q_i}$ is solvable, so the Legendre-symbol $\left(\frac{a}{q_i}\right) = 1$ for all $q_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$. And so their powers and the whole product must be one, too.

Comment: @aRaRa: yes, it's overkill to use the CRT to get the implication you want, but the point of using the CRT is to see exactly why the reverse implication fails.